# Variables appear out of order when expanded in Here-String function

Tags: powershell

I just ran into what I think is a very strange issue, but it's very possible I'm just doing something wrong.

When I run this code:

```
Function OutOfOrder($animal,$verb,$adjective) {
@"
The quick brown $animal $verb over the $adjective dog
"@
}

OutOfOrder("fox","jumped","lazy")
```

This is the output I receive:

```
The quick brown fox jumped lazy  over the  dog
```

Behavior is the same in PS 2.0 and 3.0. What gives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake.  You shouldn't use parens and commas when calling a powershell function.

You passed an array of 3 strings to the first parameter and the other 2 came across empty.

Try this:

```
 OutOfOrder "fox" "jumped" "lazy"
```